# Curl sending blank header(testing Java web server)

Tags: java, curl

I am testing my web server by sending it requests from cURL. When I send this command:

```
curl -H "_ADD_CLASS*21112*ab*https://somewebsite" 127.0.0.1:12345
```

to my server, I get this in my Java Socket

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
Host: 127.0.0.1:12345
Accept: */*
_ADD_CLASS*21112*ab*https://somewebsite
```

This is what I was expecting.

When I send this request to my server using cURL though, it does not send the header for some reason:

```
curl -H "REMOVE_CLASS*21111*a" 127.0.0.1:12345

GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
Host: 127.0.0.1:12345
Accept: */*
"" (as shown in java)
```

Any idea why the second request is showing up as ""? Here is some code:

```
private static void handleRequest(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    String socketData = null;
    String[] commands;
    while (br.ready()) {
        socketData = br.readLine();
        //parse command
        if (socketData.compareTo("") == 0) {
            //Log error
            break;
        }else {
            if (socketData.charAt(0) != '_') continue;
            commands = socketData.split("\\*");
            if (commands[0].compareTo("_ADD_CLASS") == 0) {
                //syntax is ADD_CLASS*CRN*TOKEN*WEB_ADDRESS
                socket.close();
                addClass(commands[1], commands[2], commands[3]);
                break;
            }else if(commands[0].compareTo("_REMOVE_CLASS") == 0) {
                //syntax is REMOVE_CLASS*CRN*TOKEN
                socket.close();
                removeClass(commands[1], commands[2]);
                break;
            }else if(commands[0].compareTo("_UPDATE_TOKEN") == 0) {
                //syntax is UPDATE_TOKEN*OLD_TOKEN*NEW_TOKEN
                socket.close();
                updateDeviceToken(commands[1], commands[2]);
                break;
            }else {
                //log error
            }
    }
    }
    socket.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [HTTP Spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2), a header must have a colon in it and you're not specifying one. I'll also point you to the [cURL man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H):

> -H, --header  ... If you send the custom header with no-value then its header must be terminated with a semicolon, such as -H "X-Custom-Header;" to send "X-Custom-Header:".

With that said, why are you trying to invent your own methods using HTTP headers instead of adopting a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) style? Wouldn't it be much easier to use a JAX-RS implementation and let it handle the nitty gritty socket stuff for you? Or at the very least you could use Servlets / Filters.

Comment: I am making an iOS app that will talk to my Server..so you're saying the reason the initial request worked is because it had a colon?

Comment: Yes. curl sent the header because you specified both the key and the value for the header you wanted to send (as is required). I would still suggest really thinking about using one of many standard frameworks and design patterns for developing your web service though instead of trying to hand roll sockets especially if you're using HTTP.

Comment: Your first request would be parsed by any number of other HTTP tools as a key of "_ADD_CLASS*21112*ab*https" value of "//somewebsite"

Comment: If you're hell bent on abusing the snot out of HTTP headers though, just come up with your own key like "X-Action:" or something. (X- being conventional prefix for non-standard headers)